# bitbucket pipeline with docker container

Tags: maven, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

I have a project that I am building with maven. The test case uses test containers to start up a MS-SQLserver instance. The pipeline is currently failing.

The reason being the pipleline image I am using is:

```
image: maven:3.6.0
```

Which is devoid of docker and the sqlserver image.

My question is:

Do I create my own image with java + maven + docker + sqlserver and use that in the pipeline file

or

Just have commands in the pipeline file to install what I need? I would assume this would be the slower options WRT build time

---

Example of bitbucket pipeline fail with testcontainers ryuk enabled:

```
2019-09-09 07:21:22.719  WARN 416 --- [containers-ryuk] o.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper  : Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:32768
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper$FilterRegistry.register(ResourceReaper.java:380) ~[testcontainers-1.11.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to work with your *Bitbucket Pipelines* by disabling [Ryuk](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#disabling-ryuk). You also need to add `docker` as a service in your script as follows:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
          # Your commands should come after setting the environment variable above
          # ...
          # ...
        services:
          - docker
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```

Detailed information regarding this is provided [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/bitbucket_pipelines/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "docker" service to your pipeline and [disable Ryuk](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#disabling-ryuk).